# When a React button is clicked the url/route changes. But the content associated with the url/route does not render

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to react, and I have many videos, but I can not find my problem. I want to open the contact me section when I click the contact me button present on the main page. When I click on the contact me button, it changes the route in the URL but does the opens the page.
When I try to open the same page by clicking the link present in the navbar, it works.

I am cleaning up while posting the question to maintain readability.

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
// Import Pages
import AboutMe from './pages/AboutMe';
import MyWork from './pages/MyWork';
import ContactMe from './pages/ContactMe';
// Router
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Nav />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <AboutMe />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/work" exact>
            <MyWork />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contact" exact>
            <ContactMe />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my AboutSection.
In my about section, when I click on my button, it enters /contact but does not open the page, but when I try to open the same route while clicking on the link from the navbar, it opens the link.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
//Images

const AboutSection = () => {
  return (
    <About>
      <Description>
        {/*This is the button */}
        <Link to="/contact">
          <motion.button variants={fade}>
            Contact Me
          </motion.button>
        </Link>
      </Description>
      <Image>
        <motion.img variants={photoAnim} src={homeImg1} alt="camera guy" />
      </Image>
      <Wave />
    </About>
  );
};

const Hide = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
`;

export default AboutSection;
```

Code of my Nav.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const Nav = () => {
  return (
      <StyledNav>
        <h1>
          <Link id="logo" to="/">
            Nitish Poonia
          </Link>
        </h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact Me</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </StyledNav>
  );
};
export default Nav;
```

My Contact me

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
//Animation
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { pageAnimation, titleAnim } from "../animation";

const ContactUs = () => {
  return (
    <ContactStyle>
      <Title>
        <Hide>
          <motion.h2 variants={titleAnim}>Get in touch.</motion.h2>
        </Hide>
        <div className="line2"></div>
      </Title>
      <div>
        <Hide>
          <Social variants={titleAnim}>
            <Circle />
            <h2>Socials</h2>
          </Social>
        </Hide>
        <Hide>
          <Social variants={titleAnim}>
            <Circle />
            <h2>Send me a message</h2>
          </Social>
        </Hide>
        <Hide>
          <Social variants={titleAnim}>
            <Circle />
            <h2>Drop an email.</h2>
          </Social>
        </Hide>
      </div>
    </ContactStyle>
  );
};



export default ContactUs;
```

Comment: Can you please add you `Contact` component code?

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be a few changes you can do towards fixing the issues. Noting them down below.

- `Switch` component should not be passed any `props`, you don't need to get `location` here using `useLocation` and pass it there and same for `key` as well. Refer [React Router Switch Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)
- Can you change the order of your routes to look like something below just to be safe. We are putting the `/` i.e. the base route at the end, so that it acts as a fallback too.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/work" exact>
       <MyWork />
     </Route>
     <Route path="/contact" exact>
       <ContactMe />
     </Route>
     <Route path="/">
       <AboutMe />
     </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This is working only for the button, and now my all other links have stopped working.

Comment: Please try to debug if you URL is changing, if so then are you correct components rendering and so on.